Should I use Deno's serve command or serve function?
Reading Deno's 2.0 announcement earlier this week, I saw that the command deno serve can now run HTTP servers in parallel. In my own code, I've been using the function Deno.serve(): probably copied from one of the Deno by example snippets and to bring up the server that way I use the command deno run.
Which one should I be using: the command or the function? Are they the same thing? If I run deno serve will I be able to compile my server later with deno compile?
In other words: what are the differences; advantages; and disadvantages for deno serve and Deno.serve()?

Good question! My understanding is that if you're using the deno serve interface, then Deno will actually spin up multiple instances of your server on different threads and distribute requests between them, whereas if you're using deno run you're only going to get a single thread (since that thread directly controls the port binding). I haven't heard about any way to compile a deno serve, so maybe it's not possible but I hope it is. (I'm not confident about any of this, so I'm leaving a comment for now, somebody who knows better can leave an answer.)

A multiple-instance server running in parallel has tremendous implications for design compared to single-instance so I find it's weird that this isn't thoroughly documented in the deno serve documentation, especially after 2.0 coming out this week mentioning it.
So I'm not sure this is the answer... but it could be! Thank you for your comment!

You're right, the documentation seems quite lacking here. It seems like the parallelism isn't automatic, but is supported: there's a --parallel flag to enable it, added in PR 24920 and mentioned in the --help usage output, but it's not mentioned in any of the online documentation I could find. It is described in a section in the Deno 1.46 release notes, which must be what I was mis-remembering.
